# Understanding control structure of nested loops in Python

Tags: loops, nested-loops

All of the options below produce the same output, but I'm not quite understanding why. Is anyone able to explain why multiple values are printed for j on each line? I would think it would print either 0 every time when it is set equal to 0 or print 1, 2, 3, 4 instead.

Option 1:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    j = 0
    while j < i:
        print(j, end = " ")
        j += 1
    print("")

Option 2:

for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(j, end = " ")
    print("")

Option 3:

i = 1
while i < 6:
    j = 0
    while j < i:
        print(j, end = " ")
        j += 1
    i += 1
    print("")
```

Output:

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the inner `while/for` loop that one or more digits are printed on a single line.

As the value of `i` increments in the outer loop, the number of nested iterations increase with increasing value of `i`.

The digits are printed on the same line in inner loop due to `end=" "` argument to the first `print` statement and the next sequence appears on the new line because the second `print` statement in the outer iteration does not contain any such argument.

In order to gain better understanding, make following changes to your code, one by one and test run to see the effects:

- Replace `i` in the inner loop with some constant value
- Replace the space in `end = " "` with something else, e.g. `end = "x"`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Makes total sense. I was assuming a static/constant value for i for some reason, which wasn't true. Thank you!

Comment: @python_forecaster : in that case i expected you to mark it as selected answer

Comment: This is my second post ever. Wasn't exactly sure how to do that. Done!